# Unable to remove (default?) header

Tags: react-native, expo

I am working on a RN app, but I can't seem to get rid of what appears to be a default header at the very top.

At first I thought that this might have to do with react-navigation or something, but even if I render only some text:

```js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{ backgroundColor: '#e0e0e0', height: '100%'  }}>
      <Text>WHY IS THERE A HEADER ABOVE ME?</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I still get this header on top:

[image]

I have also tried to hide the `StatusBar`:

```js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar hidden />
      <View style={{ backgroundColor: '#e0e0e0', height: '100%'  }}>
        <Text>WHY IS THERE A HEADER ABOVE ME?</Text>
      </View>
    </>
  );
};
```

Something got removed apparently, as the header is now black, but as you can see, there is still a gap between the view and the top of the screen.

[image]